# ValueError loading data for scipy.odr regression

Tags: python, scipy, regression

I recently tried to use scipy.odr package to conduct a regression analysis. Whenever I try to load a list of data where the elements depend on a function, a value error is raised:

`ValueError: x could not be made into a suitable array`

I have been using the same kind of programming to make fits using scipy's leastsq and curve_fit routines without problems.

Any idea of what to change and how to proceed? Thanks a lot...

Here I include a minimal working example:

```
from scipy import odr
from functools import partial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### choose select=0 and for myModel a list of elements is called which are a function of some parameters
### this results in error message: ValueError: x could not be made into a suitable array
### choose select=1, the function temp is exlcuded, and a fit is generated
### what do i have to do in order to run the programm successfully using select=0? 

## choose here!
select=1

pfit=[1.0,1.0]
q0=[1,2,3,4,5]
q1=[3,8,10,19,27]


def temp(par, val):
    p1,p2=par       
    temp_out = p1*val**p2
    return temp_out

def fodr(a,x):
    if select==0:
        fitf = np.array([xi(a) for xi in x])
    else:          
        fitf= a[0]*x**a[1]
    return fitf

# define model
myModel = odr.Model(fodr)
# load data
damy=q1
if select==0:
    damx=[]
    for el in q0:
        elm=partial(temp,val=el)
        damx.append(elm)
    #damx=[el(pfit) for el in damx]  # check that function temp works fine
    #print damx
else:   
    damx=q0

myData = odr.Data(damx, damy)   
myOdr = odr.ODR(myData, myModel , beta0=pfit, maxit=100, ifixb=[1,1])   
out = myOdr.run()
out.pprint()
```

Edit:

@ Robert:
Thanks for your reply. I am using scipy version '0.14.0'. Using select==0 in my minimal example I get following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scipy-odr.py", line 48, in <module>
out = myOdr.run()
File "/home/tg/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/odr/odrpack.py", line 1061, in run
self.output = Output(odr(*args, **kwds))
ValueError: x could not be made into a suitable array
```

Comment: Please post a complete traceback, and state the version of scipy that you are using. Your example works fine for me.

Comment: Hi Robert, I edited my question. Hope this will help to solve the issue. Thx a lot - Tobi

Answer (score 0):

In short, your code does not work because `damx` is a now a `list` of `functools.partial`.

`scipy.odr` is a simple wrapper around `Fortran` Orthogonal Distance Regression (`ODRPACK`), both xdata and ydata have to be numerical since they will be converted to some `Fortran` type under the hood. It doesn't know what to do with a `list` of `functools.partial`, therefore the error.

Comment: I understand that there must be an issue with the list of  functools.partial elements. I am wondering, however, how Robert was able to run the example without problems?

Comment: I don't know, may be he forget to change the line `select=1` to `select=0`?

Comment: maybe, anyway, thanks for your help. I will try to find a workaround for my problem...